# Echo table field values to a dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu, echo, field

I've been consulting stack overflow for quite some time now.
I'm developing a system for article management and I encountered a problem.

How do I echo a field values to a dropdown `select` from a database table?

I have managed to echo it using this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT catName FROM tblCat");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "$row['catName']";
    echo "`<br />`";
}
```

But when I edited the code to this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT catName FROM tblCat");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "`<select>`";
    echo "`<option value='{$row['catName']}'>`";
    echo "`</select>`";
}
```

I got no result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) good tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<select>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT catName FROM tblCat");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo "<option value='{$row['catName']}'>{$row['catName']}</option>";

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: this is correct, he was including the select tag in the loop, and also he was using the option tag incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

You need to output it twice, you're only setting value, you need the label too:

```
 echo "<option value='{$row['catName']}'>{$row['catName']}</option>";
```